# Angular js table row deletion

Tags: angularjs

I'm sorry if I answer you after a long time but the problem, unfortunately, has come back. Now in a different way. In any case, the page always deletes the first row or the last row instead of the row on which I click the delete button FILE HTML

enter code here

```
<tr ng-repeat='i in cars'> <!--SE INSERISCO INCREMENTO AUTOMATICO MI 
RIMUOVE SEMPRE ULTIMA RIGA-->
<td class="dimensione">{{$index + 1}}</td>
<td class="dimensione">{{i.targaauto}}</td>
<td class="dimensione">{{i.datiintestatario}}</td>
<td class="dimensione">{{i.marca}}</td>
<td><button type="button" class='btn btn-danger' ng- 
click='rigadaeliminare(index)' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs- 
target='#elimina'>ELIMINA</button></td>
</tr>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rimuovi()" 
data-bs-dismiss="modal">OK</button>

FILE JS

$scope.rigadaeliminare = function(index) {
$scope.idcancellare = index;
};


$scope.rimuovi = function () {
$scope.cars.splice($scope.idcancellare, 1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have a typo:

`ng-click='rigadaeliminare($index)'` - not `ng-click='rigadaeliminare(index)'`

However, the only reason I can figure that you are doing this in 2 steps is so you can allow for multiple deletes at one time. In that case, you'll need to track an array. Here's one way. In this method, I made it so if you click 'ELIMINA' it will add that index to the array and change the button text to 'CANCEL', in case the user changes their mind.

In the actual removal function, rather than loop through the list of indexes and splice them out (which won't work because as soon as you splice the array all the indexes re-index), use indexOf and find the value.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.eliminaIds = [];
    $scope.cars = [{
        targaauto: "Ferarri",
        datiintestatario: "Something",
        marca: "1998"
      },
      {
        targaauto: "Audi",
        datiintestatario: "Something",
        marca: "1998"
      },
      {
        targaauto: "Mazda",
        datiintestatario: "Something",
        marca: "1998"
      }
    ];
    $scope.rigadaeliminare = function(index) {
      let ex = $scope.eliminaIds.indexOf(index);
      if (ex === -1) $scope.eliminaIds.push(index)
      else $scope.eliminaIds.splice(ex, 1);
    };


    $scope.rimuovi = function() {
      console.log("D")
      $scope.eliminaIds.forEach(i => {
        $scope.cars.splice($scope.cars.indexOf(i), 1);
      })
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat='i in cars'>
      <!--SE INSERISCO INCREMENTO AUTOMATICO MI 
    RIMUOVE SEMPRE ULTIMA RIGA-->
      <td class="dimensione">{{$index + 1}}</td>
      <td class="dimensione">{{i.targaauto}}</td>
      <td class="dimensione">{{i.datiintestatario}}</td>
      <td class="dimensione">{{i.marca}}</td>
      <td><button type="button" class='btn btn-danger' ng-click='rigadaeliminare($index)' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs- target='#elimina'>{{eliminaIds.indexOf($index) === -1 ? "ELIMINA" : "Cancel"}}</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rimuovi()" data-bs-dismiss="modal">OK</button>



</div>
```